# Why is my code outputting 0 when I run it? whats wrong and how do I fix it?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, output, average

This is my code made to show the sum and average of an array using a for loop but when I run it it just outputs 0 for both the sum and average.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    float grades[12] = {85.0, 77.0, 15.0, 100.0, 90.0, 98.0, 62.0, 84.0, 86.0, 70.0, 100.0, 99.0};
    int counter;
    float average;
    float sum = 0.0;

    for(counter = 0; counter == 12; counter++){

        sum = sum + grades[counter];
    } 

    average = sum/12;

    printf("The sum of the grades is: %f \n", sum);
    printf("The average of the grades are: %f \n", average);

    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

for-loops are:  `for(init; while; increment)`

Note that this is WHILE, not UNTIL

Your loop will never run:

```
for(counter = 0; counter == 12; counter++){
```

because 0 is never equal to 12.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for`-loop is wrong. Try

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 12; counter++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` stops as soon as its condition is false. Your condition, `counter == 12`, is false on the first iteration, so the loop never runs.